# Swift - Flipping view controllers disables IBOutlets

Tags: swift, uianimation

My app starts and I'm presenting *VC1* **on the top** of tabBarController

`tabBarController?.present(VC1, animated: false, completion: nil)`

It presents first page and I have another page *VC2*.
I make flip transition between these 2 pages by posting notification to the current opened *VC0* in the tabBarController(**not the presented one, but the one who is in index 0 in the tabBarController**).The notifications triggers:

```
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        let VC2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "VC2") as! VC2
        UIView.transition(from: topController.view, to: VC2.view, duration: 0.85, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft])
    }
```

This makes the flip, but it looks like the IBOutlets are not connected and the click is not detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't keep any reference if VC2. So IBOutlet's action do not perform. You can try this example. It may be helpful for you.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func gotoNextPage(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        GlobalVariable.transitionViewFrom(from: self, to: vc, subtype: nil, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft])
    }
}

class GlobalVariable: NSObject {
    private static var sharedManager: GlobalVariable!
    public var allViewInstantController: [UIViewController]=[UIViewController]()
    public static let NUMBER_OF_VIEWCONTROLLER_OPEN_AT_A_TIME:Int = 5

    static func shared() -> GlobalVariable {
        if(sharedManager==nil){
            sharedManager=GlobalVariable()
        }
        return sharedManager
    }
    override private init() {
    }

    static func transitionViewFrom(from:UIViewController, to:UIViewController, subtype:CATransitionSubtype? = nil, options: UIView.AnimationOptions? = nil) -> Void {
        let timeDelay:Double=0.5
        GlobalVariable.checkPreviousView(_view:to)
        GlobalVariable.splashViewFrom(from: from, to:to, isAdd:true, subtype:subtype, options: options, timeDelay: timeDelay)
    }

    static func checkPreviousView(_view:UIViewController) -> Void {
        GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.append(_view)
        if(GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.count>GlobalVariable.NUMBER_OF_VIEWCONTROLLER_OPEN_AT_A_TIME){
            let myViewController = GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.first
            myViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.removeFirst()
        }
    }

    static func splashViewFrom(from:UIViewController, to:UIViewController, isAdd:Bool, subtype:CATransitionSubtype? = nil, options: UIView.AnimationOptions? = nil, timeDelay:Double) -> Void {
        do {
            if let subtype = subtype {
                let transition = CATransition()
                transition.duration = 0.25
                transition.isRemovedOnCompletion = true;
                transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
                transition.type = CATransitionType.push
                transition.subtype  = subtype
                from.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
            }else if let options = options {
                UIView.transition(from: from.view, to: to.view, duration: timeDelay, options: options)
            }

            if(!isAdd){
                from.view.removeFromSuperview()
                if(GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.count>0){
                    GlobalVariable.shared().allViewInstantController.removeLast()
                }
            }else{
                if subtype != nil {
                    from.view.addSubview(to.view)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static func dismissViewFrom(viewController:UIViewController, subtype:CATransitionSubtype) -> Void {
        let timeDelay=0.5
        GlobalVariable.splashViewFrom(from: viewController, to: UIViewController(), isAdd:false, subtype:subtype, timeDelay: timeDelay)
    }
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBAction func previousPage(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        GlobalVariable.transitionViewFrom(from: self, to: vc, subtype: nil, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft])
    }
}
```

For flip just change type. And change accordingly for back page transaction.

```
transition.type = CATransitionType(rawValue: "flip")
```

Another solution, you can try this.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GlobalVariable.shared().rootViewController=self
    }
    @IBAction func gotoNextPage(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        UIView.transition(from: self.view, to: vc.view, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft])
    }
}

class GlobalVariable: NSObject {
    private static var sharedManager: GlobalVariable!
    public var rootViewController: UIViewController?
    static func shared() -> GlobalVariable {
        if(sharedManager==nil){
            sharedManager=GlobalVariable()
        }
        return sharedManager
    }
    override private init() {
    }
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GlobalVariable.shared().rootViewController=self
    }

    @IBAction func previousPage(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        UIView.transition(from: self.view, to: vc.view, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need FLIP of the views, not page scrolling

Comment: Both solutions makes my code with the inactive @IBOutlers. Yesterday the code that you gave me worked. Maybe the problem is that I'm executing GlobalVariable in another view controller with Notification using topController... Idk...

Comment: Yeah now I changed transition.type = CATransitionType(rawValue: "flip") with the yesterday code and it worked.